# how to save the json file as csv file by the name of the json file with .csv extension

Tags: python, csv

I have a set of 200 JSON file in a folder, i have written a code to take each file from the folder and then convert the JSON files to data-frame do the necessary step and finally save the data-frame as a csv file,the problem i face is to save the csv file, i wanted to save the file as csv in the name of the JSON file.

Since i am taking the folder and processing the files one by one how can i do that

i tried  this form

df.to_csv(filename)

but i have to give the filename

Comment: You need to investigate the `os.path` functions, like `splitext()`

Comment: (name, extension) = os.path.splitext(filename)   i have used this to get the file name how can i use this name to save as a csv file

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not accessing the file by manually calling its name:

```py
with open('whatever.json', 'rb') as file
```

And using something like glob. I would do something like this:

```py
import os

#File = to whatever variable name you have assigned to the opened json file

filename = os.path.basename(File.name)
filename = filename.split('.')[0]
filename += '.csv'
```

as requested:

```py
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(your csv data)
    file.close()
```

Comment: now i have got the name of the json file, how can i use this to save my dataframe as csv using this name